# PouchDB - How does Auto-Compaction affect 2 way replication?

Tags: replication, pouchdb

I am running a Chromium based app that is replicating with my master database (2 way).

How does Auto-Compaction on my Client Side affect the Server DB, do my Revs also get deleted from Server?

Any Ideas? I searched the Docs for Auto Compaction it doesn't mention much regarding how it affects replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compaction only affects the database that you are compacting. Any non-leaf revisions are removed, and since only leaf revisions are considered during replication, it has no impact on the replication process.

On the other hand, there is an alternative replicator I wrote called [pouchdb-full-sync](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-full-sync), and it will replicate all revisions (leafs and non-leafs), so it would be affected by compaction.